# Issue with routing in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have a web app. Back end with node and front end with React. Setup (simplified) goes like this:

```
index.js (the server)
client
package.json
```

**The client**

Now, the `client` folder contains a front end web application, its contents are basically same as what you get when you type create-react-app.

Inside `client` there is a `build` folder which I created by running `npm run build` from within the `client` folder.

**Server**

Now, the `index.js` from my main folder acts as the node server, inside it I have a line like:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client/build"));
```

Using this approach I have merged my node server and a client front end application (located inside client folder). You can see I told the server to serve files from the `client/build`.

All was working fine, till I encountered this.

If I click a react button in my client app which manually calls my router using say:

```
this.props.router.push('/listmovies');
```

it correctly shows the page.

But if I type same page in URL address bar and hit ENTER I get error:

> Cannot GET /listmovies

The latter error I am pretty sure comes from node server. Because there is no listener for `listmovies` in `index.js` (and there should not be). You see basically I think node is intercepting the call and giving me an error. Whereas in my former case where I called `router.push` I get a correct page.

I hope I managed to explain my problem. Can someone help how to solve this issue?

Comment: can you add your `index.js` configuration? it looks like you missing something there

Comment: @QoP The react app is contained in "client" folder as I stated in my question. And it was created using create-react-app starter.

Comment: You have to redirect all the *unmatched* routes to your `index.html`, something like this should work `app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));`, add it as the *last route*, before `app.listen(...)`

Comment: @QoP Bingo! I think it works now

Comment: @QoP Thanks for great answer. Btw. is it common you see such setup when people want to combine react and node?

Comment: Yeah! Its a common setup. You can also pre-render your app in the server and and serve it instead of the `index.html`. Here's [a repo](https://github.com/lmammino/judo-heroes/blob/master/src/server.js#L22) which implements it.

Comment: @QoP Ok, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the `express` application redirect all requests to the main `React` file so `react-router` can take over. Something like this below the `app.use`.

```
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html')
    })
```

This basically handles all wildcards and points it to the `index.html`. Mind you if you are also implementing API routes on the `express` app have them above this wildcard statement because otherwise it will intercept them and treat them as client side `react-router` routes instead of server-side API routes.